# Orkut (GMail)- Google Talk Chat Program

Tags: instant-messaging

I am new to ubuntu, and can't find Google talk for ubuntu, How can I use chat on orkut.com which uses GMail sign in programme and I use Google talk to chat on windows.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Yahoo chat with Empathy. Simply go to `Edit->Accounts` then click 'Add...' and choose Yahoo as the protocol. You need to enter your Yahoo account details.

[image: Add Yahoo account]

Comment: I think empathy has this ability because under Advanced there is a 'Room List Locale' option. I can't test this because I don't have a Yahoo account.

Answer (score 2):

Empathy has Google Talk support. Start Empathy, click Edit -> Accounts, then Add. Choose Google Talk from the Protocol list.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) can do Yahoo Group Chat.